# Allow only number after 2 characters (My regex 'eat' the first item, see the code)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm creating a validating in my input.

It must allow only numbers and logical operators: `0` to `9` and `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=`

Ok. Its already working, but the logical operators only can be typeds in first and second fields, like this:

Input must allow: `>=10`, `>100`, `<=12123` 
Input must not allow: `>=1212>`, `>=2<<`, `>2=>`

That is, if the user typed a logical operator in the first and/or second field, he can't typed any logical operator again.

In my code, I check the length of `input` and if it be bigger than 3 I rewrite the regex, but the first character is 'eated'.

See my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var txt = $('#txt');
  var conteudo = txt.val();
  
  $('#txt').on('input', function (event) {    
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\>\<\=]|^0+(?!$)/g, '');    
    var qtd = event.target.value;           
    if(qtd.length > 3){      
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\=]|^0+(?!$)/g, '');        
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

How I can implements it?

Input must allow: `>=10`, `>100`, `<=12123` 
Input must not allow: `>=1212>`, `>=2<<`, `>2=>`

---edit-----
Input must allow: `>=10`, `>100`, `<=12123`, `121` 
Input must not allow: `>=1212>`, `>=2<<`, `>2=>`, `345<3`, `2<=3`

Comment: Try `^[<>]=?(?!0*$)\d+$` on `match()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the last valid value and check the new one and replace it with the last one if not match the condition.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var txt = $('#txt');
  var last = '';
  
  $('#txt').on('input', function (event) {
    if (this.value && !/^([<>]=?)?\d+$/.test(this.value + '0')) { // add zero for checking starting values
        this.value = last;
    }
    last = this.value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Comment: In this sample I can't erase the input. When I type a logical operator, it can't be erased :/

Comment: i added a check for not empty strings.

Comment: Regex is a different and interesting thing. Thanks a lot Nina!